# Java Generics Type Mismatch When Using Nested Lower Bound

Tags: java, generics, contravariance

I am having trouble understanding why the compiler is not allowing the following assignment:

```
Consumer<Collection<? super Project>> consumer = new Consumer<Collection<Project>>(){};
```

I generally understand how to use "? super ..." and understand why it works fine in these similar examples:

```
Consumer<? super Project> projectConsumer = new Consumer<Project>(){};
```

or

```
Consumer<? super Project> objectConsumer = new Consumer<Object>(){};
```

or even

```
Collection<? super Project> objectCollection = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

However I don't see how these differ from the first example.
 Could someone please explain why the first example does not compile?

Comment: They differ because the nesting indeed makes a difference.  A wildcard at the outermost level of the type argument expresses the possibility of multiple conforming types.  A wildcard more deeply nested, on the other hand, is an inherent part of the type argument.

Comment: `Consumer<? extends Collection<? super Project>>` would work. It's the same reason you can't assign a `List<Dog>` to a `List<Animal>`.

Comment: Consider `List<List<?>>`: a `List` that can accept any `List` as an element.  For example, it allows both a `List<Integer>` and a `List<String>` as elements, at the same time.  Neither a `List<List<String>>` nor a `List<List<Integer>>` can do that, so neither of them is a subtype of `List<List<?>>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java generics compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276797/java-generics-compiler-error)